# Executing python script in 5 nodes concurrently and compare the output

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, architecture

I'm trying to build an architecture which does the following steps:

1. Single python script which runs in 5 nodes for every minute in a span of 1 hour.
2. every minute data output should be computed and send the o/p to a DB.

Limitations:

1. If the python script is continuously executing for more than 1 minute, then there should be another trigger again in next minute.
2. The computing of the data should be done separately for every minute and can be sent to DB.

Please let me know how I can achieve the architecture for this scenario other than multithreading/multiprocessing.

Comment: if `"5 nodes"` means 5 computers with Linux then every Linux can use tasks scheduler `cron` to execute the same script every 1 minut in span of 1 hour. And it will run it even if previous script is still running.

Comment: if you mean one computer with Linux then you can also use `cron` to run the same script every 1 minut and this script can run 5 processes/threads.

Comment: if you don't like modules `threading` and `multiprocessing` then you have also modules [joblib.Parallel](https://joblib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html), [Dask](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/), [Ray](https://docs.ray.io/en/releases-1.5.0/iter.html). And if you don't like Linux `cron` then you have modules like [sched](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sched.html) or [APScheduler](https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/3.x/userguide.html)

Comment: Thanks https://stackoverflow.com/users/1832058/furas for the solution, I thought of the same and did a cron job and it's working now.

Comment: instead of link to my profile you can use @furas and stackoveflow will automatically inform me